# firebase setPriority permisions_denied

Tags: firebase

Documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/setpriority.html

Isn't there missing something important?

I am trying to update the priority of the group by some auth user. And i am able to do it only when i am authenticated as an owner of the group and i have no idea why and HOW TO GRANT ACCESS ONLY FOR UPDATING THE PRIORITY TO THE ALL AUTH USERS AS I DID WITH "membersCount".

```
// GROUPS
"groups": {
  "$subCategoryId": {      
    "$groupId": {
      // ONLY OWNER OF GROUP CAN UPDATE THE userId, name, hashTag, categoryId
      // 
      // The first init has to have userId, name, categoryId
      // 
      // Anyone can update the membersCount
      ".write": "newData.hasChildren(['userId','name','categoryId']) || !data.exists() || auth != null",
      "userId": {
        ".validate": "auth.uid == newData.val()"
      },
      "name": {
        ".validate": "newData.val() != '' && newData.val().length < 30 && (data.parent().child('userId').val() == auth.uid || !data.parent().child('userId').exists())"
      },
      "hashTag": {
        ".validate": "(data.parent().child('userId').val() == auth.uid || !data.parent().child('userId').exists())"
      },
      "categoryId": {
        ".validate": "newData.val() != '' && root.child('categories').child(newData.val()).exists() && root.child('subcategories').child(newData.val()).child($subCategoryId).exists() && (data.parent().child('userId').val() == auth.uid || !data.parent().child('userId').exists())"
      },
      "membersCount": {
        ".write": "auth != null && newData.isNumber() && (data.val()+1 == newData.val() || data.val()-1 == newData.val() )"  
      }
    }
  }    
},
```

When i tried update({ '.priority': 2}) i got:

Uncaught Error: update() does not currently support updating .priority.

Answer (score 0):

The error message has nothing to do with security rules in this case. You can't update a priority using the update() command. You can do it by using `setPriority(2)`.

If you want to reference priorities in your security rules, you can do that with [getPriority](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rulesdatasnapshot/getpriority.html).

Comment: yea i know there is no possibility to update the priority. It was just my tried. But i can't do setPriority(2) with such a security rules. It will throw access_denied error. I can do it only if i am the owner (can write to everything) but if i am allowed to write to only one field to example membersCount... i can't update priority. So my question is if there is some workaround to grant access for "updating" the priority with such a rules if i am not the owner of the group.